# Only allow west european names/chars without regex

Tags: javafx, filter

This is my filter:

```
public class FilterName implements UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> {

    @Override
    public TextFormatter.Change apply(TextFormatter.Change tfc) {
        String eingabe = tfc.getText();
        for (int i = 0; i < eingabe.length(); i++) {
            char c = eingabe.charAt(i);
            if (!(Character.isAlphabetic(c) || c == ' ' || c == '-')) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                return null;
            }
        }
        return tfc;
    }
}
```

I use this filter to filter only chars. But I just want to allow west european names. Doing this with regex is really hard and I want to avoid that. The problem here is that this solution also allows non-european characters like kanji or hiragana etc. Is there a way that I can only allow west european names/chars like that?

EDIT: This is the regex that I want to allow: ^[-.a-zA-Z0-9'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞ\ßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ ]*$